# Consume rabbitmq messages by id

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm creating an app using NodeJS and RabbitMQ and there's a necessity of having an endpoint that returns all messages that has a certain id, currently I'm doing it by parsing the JSON body but I don't think this will be a good idea in the future, how can I achieve this without having to parse the JSON body?

Thanks, tell me if you have any questions on this one :)

Comment: Do you mean, you have a RabbitMQ consumer, and keep all consumed messages in memory or in a database? Then have a web api that retrieves those stored messages?

Comment: Currently they are being persisted, the problem is getting how can I filter the messages consumed by id, it could be a routingKey but wouldn't that fill up quickly?

Comment: As a general rule, don't worry about optimization until you need to. Programs are very fast these days, even without trying. Deserializing a JSON payload is very fast. and unlikely to be a bottle neck. I would deserialize it, check the id, and then persist the record if the id met the criteria. That sounds good enough to me.

Comment: Do that first, and measure the performance. If it's not good enough, there could be other tricks to apply, but you wont know without measuring. Trying to guess optimization is hard, and quite often, surprisingly unsuccessful. Leading programmers say it. I've experienced it.

Comment: Are you parsing the JSON on the consumer end or the publisher end?